# BASH shell script searching and displaying a pattern

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep

I am trying to create a BASH shell script in which I prompt the user to enter an animal, and return "The $animal has (number I set in case statement) legs"

I am using a case statement for this.  My current statement is below:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Enter an animal: "
read animal

case $animal in
spider|octopus) echo "The $animal has 8 legs";;
horse|dog) echo "The $animal has 4 legs";;
kangaroo|person) echo "The $animal has 2 legs";;
cat|cow) echo "The $ animal has 4 legs";;
*) echo "The $animal has an unknown number of legs"
esac
```

For a cat or cow, I need to be able to echo "The (xyz) (cat or cow) has 4 legs"  I am thinking of using a grep somewhere but don't know if that is the best option for this.  Can anyone help out?

Thanks!

Comment: Replace `$ animal` with `$animal`.

Comment: Really, the `case` statement only needs to set something like `n=8` or `n="an unknown number of"`, etc for each category. Afterwards, you can have a single statement `echo "The $animal has $n legs".

Comment: @Cyrus thanks for that - didn't recognize I was missing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [chepner's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49480723/bash-shell-script-searching-and-displaying-a-pattern#comment85964442_49480723):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Enter an animal: "
read -r animal

case $animal in
  spider|octopus)       n=8;;
  horse|dog)            n=4;;
  kangaroo|person)      n=2;;
  cat|cow)              n=4;;
  *)                    n="an unknown number of"
esac

echo "The $animal has $n legs"
```

Comment: If I enter "tom cat" when prompted for an animal, the goal is to be able to display "The tom cat has 4 legs".  Or if I enter brown cow, I should be able to display "The brown cow has 4 legs"

Answer (score 0):

It seems that adding *cat|*cow) instead of cat|cow) worked without any need for grep.  Thanks